# software-properties-gtk crashes on startup (19.10)

Tags: package-management, python, software-center, additional-drivers

I am currently using Ubuntu 19.10 and trying to open 'additional drivers' results in the program crashing.
When I start it from the terminal, I get the following traceback:

```
philip@philip-hp-pavilion:/usr/bin$ software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in 
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 58, in 
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 64, in 
    from . import shortcuts
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 23, in 
    _DEF_CODENAME = aptsources.distro.get_distro().codename
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 596, in get_distro
    is_like = os_result.get('ID_LIKE', [])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I sadly have no clue how it started (it did work a few days ago). I guess maybe something is using a wrong python, but have not used Linux for long enough to know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was found for @DoubleSteakHouse

['Additional Drivers' stürzt ab › System einrichten und verwalten › Systemverwaltung, Installation, Aktualisierung](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/additional-drivers-stuerzt-ab/)

sorry german community
His/Her system looses the softlink /etc/os-release to /usr/lib/os-release

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/os-release /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Beat me. Thanks for linking the solution!

Comment: Maybe Taomon Wil beat you. 