# Unable to add ondrej repository apt in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, php, ppa

I am unable to add ondrej to my Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

The above command returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 363, in <module>
    addaptrepo = AddAptRepository()
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 41, in __init__
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/focal
```

Following is the LSB release information.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS  
Release:    20.04 
Codename:       focal
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

End goal: I want to be able to install PHP 8.1 extensions from apt

---

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

```
apt-cache policy -> https://pastebin.com/84HauP14
aptitude search ~o -> https://pastebin.com/VhaW9qWq
namei /etc/os-release -> https://pastebin.com/XwjZHkKa
cat /etc/os-release -> https://pastebin.com/CywsZvEh
```

Comment: @guiverc it's mostly brand new server with very minimal changes. The output for python3 --version is "Python 3.8.10"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib python-apt-common python3 python3-apt python3-certifi python3-chardet python3-dbus python3-distro-info python3-gi python3-idna python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-six python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 python3.8 python3.8-minimal software-properties-common` and then run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` again.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/49040/apt-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-error/

Comment: @N0rbert tried the first command, still the same error

Comment: @pLumo DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"

Comment: Please upload output of `apt-cache policy` and `aptitude search ~o` to the pastebin and share link.

Comment: @N0rbert apt-cache policy -> https://pastebin.com/84HauP14 aptitude search ~o -> https://pastebin.com/VhaW9qWq

Comment: `namei /etc/os-release` please.  It reminds me on this  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190336/software-properties-gtk-crashes-on-startup-19-10/1190636#1190636

Comment: @nobody f: /etc/os-release
 d /
 d etc
 l os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release
   d ..
   d usr
   d lib
   - os-release

Comment: Okay, the link is there. Checking correct content. `cat /etc/os-release ` Please [edit] your question for output; it is hard to read in comments without codeblock.

Comment: @nobody added pastebin to the questions

Comment: looks normal python3 version on your system too; out of idea in the moment. And it is also not a problem with the ppa I could add it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @nobody No worries. For the moment, I manually added the repo and public key.

Comment: try to reinstall your python3 and add the repo again `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could not get the `add-apt-repository` command to work so I added the repository and the signing key manually using the following commands:

1. Open the `sources.list` file with a text editor (for example `nano`):

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add the following lines to the file:

   ```
   deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main 
   #deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main
   ```
3. Add the repository signing key:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4f4ea0aae5267a6c
   ```

Comment: thank bro, save my day......

Comment: Where did you get the repository signing key?

Comment: the add-apt-repository is part of the software-properties-common apt package, so you'd need to first install that one obv. -> the keys will be imported automatically when adding the repository

Answer (score 2):

I solved with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

As cloclw0rk wrote:

> the add-apt-repository is part of the software-properties-common apt
> package, so you'd need to first install that one obv. -> the keys will
> be imported automatically when adding the repository –  clockw0rk

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib python-apt-common python3 python3-apt python3-certifi python3-chardet python3-dbus python3-distro-info python3-gi python3-idna python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-six python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 python3.8 python3.8-minimal software-properties-common
```

Then try to add new repository